# Can't try common method to prevent (google) colab from disconnecting

Tags: timeout, google-colaboratory

[Common fix to google colab fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIJfr.png)

Google colab times out after 30-90 mins instead of 12 hours, and trying

```
function ConnectButton(){
    console.log("Working"); 
    document.querySelector("#connect").click() 
}
setInterval(ConnectButton,60000);
```

raises errors in the inspector view. Is there a screenshot or different solution to prevent colab from disconnecting? I've already tried this solution and it doesn't work. Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

there are many ways to solve this problem, these scripts become obsolete after a while, because google isn't stupid..

I advise you to write a script for example in python that provides to make clicks for you like this:

```
import numpy as np
import time
import mouse

while True:
    random_row = np.random.random_sample()*100
    random_col = np.random.random_sample()*10
    random_time = np.random.random_sample()*np.random.random_sample() * 100
    mouse.wheel(1000)
    mouse.wheel(-1000)
    mouse.move(random_row, random_col, absolute=False, duration=0.2)
    mouse.move(-random_row, -random_col, absolute=False, duration = 0.2)
    mouse.LEFT
    time.sleep(random_time)
```

or you can generate a new cell using this javascript script like this:

```
function ClickConnect(){ 
    console.log("Working"); 
    document.querySelector("colab-toolbar-button").click() 
} setInterval(ClickConnect,60000)
```